# What is an appropriate method to label residential plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

I know in commercial/industrial applications, printed pipe label stickers are usually used to label the contents of a pipe. But in my recent home inspection, it was suggested I label some of the pipes in my home for ease of service (which I agree with). However, I'm not sure what labelling material/method would be best for various piping materials. (e.g. pvc, copper, pex)

I've heard you shouldn't put adhesive (specifically duct tape) on pex, as certain types can eat away at it. And on the other end of the spectrum, a lightweight paper/string hang tag might wear away very quickly, or the ink may fade. A metal/plastic hang tag may wear away at a pipe over time if there's vibration and contact. And sharpie directly on the pipe might rub off or fade (or have some other adverse reaction). I can't seem to find any guidance about residential plumbing labelling in my local building code, and going full "ANSI/ASME A13.1 PIPE LABELING REQUIREMENTS" seems a bit overkill. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

"Polypropylene paper" is available as a tough non-degradable paper substitute. If you write or print on it using a pigment-based ink (rather than a dye-based ink), the wording should not fade. Using a labeled strip of the "paper" closed with tape or a staple into a loose loop around the pipe/fitting/etc should work for you.